# Integrals and limits.

Tags: calculus

I have a doubt regarding the existence or not of a property that relates a limit to an integral. Let me explain better, I have seen properties that under certain properties for f, we have:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_n = \int \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n
\end{align*}
From this I am wondering if we have $G(t,x)$ then it could have a property like:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow a}\int G(t,x)dx = \int \lim_{t\rightarrow a}G(t,x)dx
\end{align*}
If the answer is that there are properties like these, I would love for you to share a bibliography with me where I can study properties like the one shown.

Comment: These limit theorems are usually covered in connection with the Lebesgue integral.  So you may see them in the future.  (The names mentioned by jacques would be explained there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G : \mathcal T \times \Omega \to \mathbb K$, where $\mathcal T$ is a sequential topological space (e.g. a metric space) and $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu )$ is a measure space, then
$$ \lim_{t \to a} \int_\Omega G(t, x)\,\mu (d x) = \int_\Omega \lim_{t \to a} G(t, x)\,\mu (dx) $$
means precisely that for any sequence $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with $t_n \to a$, for the function $f_n (x) := G(t, x)$,
$$  \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n (x)\,\mu (dx) = \int \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n (x)\,\mu(dx) . $$
So this is a trivial consequence of any theorem that enables exchange of limit and integral (such as the dominated convergence theorem or the monotone convergence theorem).

For example, in order to apply the dominated convergence theorem to this setting, a natural condition to impose on $G(t, x)$ would be that there is a neighborhood $\mathcal T \supset U \ni a$ and a $g \in L^1 (\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu )$ s.t.
$$\forall t \in U : \forall x \in \Omega: \quad \vert G(t, x) \vert \leq \vert g (x) \vert .$$
The proof that this implies the exchange of integral and limit is then straight-forward.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification